# Are harmonic functions ($\Delta u=0$) with compact support unique?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Does anyone how to solve the problem

$$ \Delta u=0$$

with $u \in R^n$ and $u(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$?

Is $u=0$ the only solution?

Many thanks.

Comment: You can use the mean value property to answer this question.

Comment: That condition is quite different from "compact support".

Comment: Yes, a bounded *harmonic* function is also constant, this is one version of Liouville's theorem.